# SAMAccountName 20 characters or less

Tags: powershell

My script pulled users from a spreadsheet and created them in AD.

```
foreach ($user in $Contractors) {
    $name = $user.Name
    $SamA = $user.SamAcc
    $first = $user.First
    $last = $user.last
    $title = $user.Title
    $email = $user.email
    $PAWD = New-RandomPassword -CharacterSetCount 1, 1, 1, 2 #A nice password function I found and called above foreach
    $UPN = $user.UPN

     $ArgHash = @{
            Name                  = $name
            GivenName             = $first
            Surname               = $last 
            SamAccountName        = $SamA 
            AccountPassword       = $(ConvertTo-SecureString $PAWD -AsPlainText -Force) 
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $True 
            DisplayName           = $name
            Enabled               = $True 
            Title                 = $title 
            Path                  = "<hidden>" 
            EmailAddress          = $email
            OfficePhone           = "<hidden>" 
            Manager               = "<hidden>"
            UserPrincipalName     = $UPN 
        }

        New-ADUser @ArgHash #create AD user
```

3 people failed due to the SamAccountName being over 20 characters.
I know now I should have checked the SamAccountName length.
Our SamAccountName are first.last format.

The best I can think to do is make a function and use if statements to create a SamAccountName 20 characters or less.

Something like this.

```
if ($SamA -gt 20) {
    if ($SamA first -gt 20 {
        $userfirst = $SamA.substring(0,10)
```

Any advice on a smart way to generate a SamAccountName that is 20 characters or less and has something like 9 characters of the first name a period and then 10 characters of the last name at max?

Or

Is there a function premade someplace that manages the combinations of first and lastname to a length?  (I searched and could not find anything)

Comment: How do you handle the case where doing the truncation would result in duplicating a sAMAccountName?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Good question. I didn't consider that either. We have not run into the problem since we are a small company but I am open to hear.

Comment: You also need to think about what happens if the persons name or lastname has less characters than you expect as substring may throw an out of bounds exception.

Comment: For what it's worth, my organization uses a unique employee ID number as part of the sAMAccountName.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - a little experimentation shows that for any string `$x`, `$x = ($x[0..9] -join "")` leaves strings of length <= 10 unchanged, and truncates anything longer to 10 chars.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yeah thats the solution to the problem, OP was using `SubString` method though which may lead into unexpected throws.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I will try your example in a function and keep you all posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x, $x = ($x[0..9] -join "")
```

works but I just learned SamAccountName will auto create with new user and my company only needs UPN.

Thanks for help.